# How to get digital signature value from x509 certificate in C#

Tags: c#, digital-signature, x509

Does anyone know how is it possible with C# to get digital signature value from x509 certificate (which is actually in x509Store and not to validate from file) and to show it for example in textbox. I know that GetRawCertDataString() returns the raw data for entire x509 certificate which includes digital signature on the last rows but I can not find a command which returns only digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

Your best way is to get ASN.1 parser and extract digital signature, or do some p/invoke stuff. You will need to use [CryptDecodeObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379911(v=vs.85).aspx) function and pass `X509_CERT` as `lpszStructType` parameter. The function returns (in the `pvStructInfo`) a pointer to a [CERT_SIGNED_CONTENT_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377540(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. This structure has `Signature` field which is a simple `BIT_BLOB` structure with byte array in the `cbData` and `pbData` fields (use `Marshal.Copy` to copy bytes from unmanaged memory to managed byte array).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but I don't know how ASN1 parser works to extract digital signature, it is my first time listening for it. Hope I will find another solution or something more for ASN1

Comment: If you need to do anything other than the simplest x509 things in you should use BouncyCastle not the built-in .NET tools. BouncyCastle requires you to understand a LOT more about what's going on, but that's not a bad thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static string Sign(this X509Certificate2 x509, string message)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] signedData;

        using (MD5 hasher = MD5.Create())
        {
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509.PrivateKey;
            signedData = rsa.SignData(data, hasher);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);// +Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine; 
        //return ByteArrayToString(signedData); //Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
    }
```

Comment: This shows how to sign using a certificate instance, not how to get the signature (from the issuing authority) out of a certificate.